# SQL 2008 table partition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, partitioning

Can you partition a table in SQL with SQL 2008 or SQL 2008 R2? Do you need enterprise edition to get partitioning? I can't find a definate answer. I did see in this [white paper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/B/D/DBDE7972-1EB9-470A-BA18-58849DB3EB3B/PartTableAndIndexStrat.docx)  it says "Table partitioning was introduced in SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition and enhanced in SQL Server 2008 Enterprise" which to me seems like I need enterprise but all of the articles I find don't mention it as a requirement.

since my management studio doesn't give me any options I have to assume that I DO need enterprise but I wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should cleear it up.  You do need the enterprise edition:

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/enterprise-compare-editions.aspx

For 2008 specifically you can click the detailed link at the bottom of this page:

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compare-std-ent.aspx

Comment: That is the 2005 link. You need http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx

Comment: @Martin: I was adding my link for 2008 at the same time you were adding your comment.

Comment: Why didn't I think to look at feature comparisons...That's why I come here.

Answer (score 1):

Yep.

[Look at this page that compares features in various editions.](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This list of 2008 features will answer your question: [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)

If you scroll down, you will see that **table and index partitioning is only available in the DataCenter and Enterprise editions**.